# How to write python code to make an already opened Hitfilm Express display on top?

Tags: python, windows, win32gui, python-re

```
import win32gui
import re


class WindowMgr:

    def __init__ (self):
        """Constructor"""
        self._handle = None

    def find_window(self, class_name, window_name=None):
        """find a window by its class_name"""
        self._handle = win32gui.FindWindow(class_name, window_name)

    def _window_enum_callback(self, hwnd, wildcard):
        """Pass to win32gui.EnumWindows() to check all the opened windows"""
        if re.match(wildcard, str(win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))) is not None:
            self._handle = hwnd

    def find_window_wildcard(self, wildcard):
        """find a window whose title matches the wildcard regex"""
        self._handle = None
        win32gui.EnumWindows(self._window_enum_callback, wildcard)

    def set_foreground(self):
        """put the window in the foreground"""
        win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(self._handle)


w = WindowMgr()
w.find_window_wildcard(".*HitFilm Express.*")
w.set_foreground()
```

this code is from another similar StackOverflow post.

It didn't work here(but it does work when I wanna display chrome on top[*Chrome])

Comment: Either your wildcard is incorrect (check window name in Task Manager) or the program have multiple windows with this header (`print` found handle in `_window_enum_callback`)

Comment: https://ibb.co/kxnQFHm

Comment: >the program have multiple windows with this header (print found handle in _window_enum_callback so?